# Upper and Lower Outer Lebesgue Densities

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In class we defined the upper outer density of a set $E$ at a point $x$ as
$$\overline{\phi}(x)=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big\{\frac{m^*(E\cap I_n)}{mI_n}:x\in I_n,mI_n<\frac{1}{n}\Big\}$$ where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. And the lower density is
$$\underline{\phi}(x)=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Big\{\frac{m^*(E\cap I_n)}{mI_n}:x\in I_n,mI_n<\frac{1}{n}\Big\}$$

I can't compute this function. I saw a different definition online concerning open balls and I got a bit more confused. Consider the following set
$$E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[-2^{-n}-2^{-n-3},-2^{-n}]\cup[2^{-n}-2^{-n-2},2^{-n}]$$
I am trying to show that $\overline{\phi}(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\underline{\phi}(0)=\frac{1}{7}$. I have tried using the intervals $I_n=[-2^{-n}-2^{-n-3},-2^{-n}]$ and some other similar ones. I seem to always get $\underline{\phi}(0)=\overline{\phi}(0)$ for some reason. And I don't understand how I'm supposed to calculate the values of these functions.